# From where does my Owin console project know the controllers in another library?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, owin

I have my API controllers in an extra project separate from the console project where Owin is hosted.

The requests to the controller work, but how is that magic done?

From where does my console project know the project where my controllers are?

Enumerate all added references and check for types inheriting from ApiController?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I might disappoint you, but there should not be any magic in there.  ;-)

I see two possibilities how your console project could know about the assembly where your controllers are:

- You are using a Custom Assemblies Resolver (like this one [here](http://www.strathweb.com/2012/06/using-controllers-from-an-external-assembly-in-asp-net-web-api/))
- You are referring something in the controllers' assembly which is causing the assembly to be loaded

I gave a try to the second option and it works like a charm:

[image]

Comment: Just realized this line between my many registerations:

builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

That way the HttpConfiguration in consoleproject knows about the controller.

Comment: best explanation and no need to mess with AssemblyResoler.